# Cant access a function that's in a js library, from another js file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am writing js code to be the front end of a application that will use jquery.dataTables to populate tables.
architure is springboot for backend, jquery and jquery datatables

the problem is that my js script cant seem to find the function in  jquery.dataTables.

I am loading the js in the html.

[here is the output of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcQyc.png)

[this is the line call that is causing issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvWbd.png)

I tried googling it, and looking on here but couldnt find any silver bullets.

the code was working on its own but we had to merge two code bases and i had to rewrite all the js and the code is not working anymore.

SO i want to populate a table in html using jquerydatatable.js

Comment: Please add some [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read about [asking good questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)